# Trigger an action assigned to a class from another button

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

Below is my button tag. By adding `show_img` class to the button and when its clicked, it shows an image.

```
<button class="show_img">Show Random Picture</button>
```

My question is how do I trigger the "show_img" by clicking #new_btn?

```
$(document).on('click', '#new_btn', function() {
    alert("new_btn clicked");
    //how to trigger "show_img" here?
});
```

Please note that `#new_btn` does not contain the `show_img` class

Comment: @guest271314 addClass doesn't trigger a click event?

Comment: At "By adding show_img class to the button _and_ when its clicked" ; initially interpreted _"and"_ literally ; e.g., adding `show_img` `class` caused image to show at another portion of `js` , `css` not present at Question

Comment: @guest271314: then why have you deleted your comment with your original answer?

Comment: Appear intital interpretation was incorrect , here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).on('click', '#new_btn', function() {
    $('.show_img').click();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `trigger` method to invoke the handler on a element.

```
$(document).on('click', '#new_btn', function() {
$('.show_img').trigger("click");
 });
```

Answer (score -1):

If you're using jQuery, which it looks like you are, you can do this:

```
$('#new_btn').on('click', function() {
  $('.show_img').click();
});
```

Comment: Can you expand on why this answer is not suitable @Beki?

Comment: compare your answer to tabz100's answer. (What does your answer do and what does tabz100's answer do.)

Comment: In other words, you need the click event to be bound to the `.show_img` class, and not the `#new_btn` ID?

Comment: Question was how do I trigger the "show_img" by clicking #new_btn? Your answer does not include `.show_img` at all?

Comment: I've updated my answer to include the `trigger()` event. Other than that, my answer does the exact same as tabz100's answer in less bytes.

Comment: Yep now you've added this line `$('.show_img').trigger("click");`